# php/AJAX - pagination error

Tags: php, ajax

Im using AJAX to get results from a query when i click in one or several labels in the computadores.php file. The results come with pagination. But when i click on page 2 (or more) it wont present anything. The pagination only presents the results of page 1. The query returns the results, but there is something wrong with the pagination, in which those results beyond page 1 arent shown. When i "inspect" the file, it indicates no error with the code, so i have no ideia what it is.

The computadores.php file

```
<ul id="paramount">

</ul>
<ul id="filtpesq">

    <li>PESQUISA<br>
        <span>Filtros</span>

        <ul><div class="t">Preço</div><div id="compind1" class="incount t"></div>
            <input id="preco" type="hidden" name="preco" value='1 AND 5000'>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op1i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="201 AND 400" data-compind1="1" data-compactiv1="no"/>
                <label id="op1" class="comppreco css-label" for="op1i">€201 - €400</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op2i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="401 AND 600" data-compind1="2" data-compactiv1="no"/>
                <label id="op2" class="comppreco css-label" for="op2i">€401 - €600</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op3i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="601 AND 800" data-compind1="3" data-compactiv1="no"/>
                <label id="op3" class="comppreco css-label" for="op3i">€601 - €800</label>
            </li>   
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op4i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="801 AND 1000" data-compind1="4" data-compactiv1="no"/>
                <label id="op4" class="comppreco css-label" for="op4i">€801 - €1000</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op5i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1001 AND 1500" data-compind1="5" data-compactiv1="no"/>
                <label id="op5" class="comppreco css-label" for="op5i">€1001 - €1500</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op6i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1501 AND 2000" data-compind1="6" data-compactiv1="no"/>
                <label id="op6" class="comppreco css-label" for="op6i">€1501 - €2000</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op7i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2001 AND 2500" data-compind1="7" data-compactiv1="no"/>
                <label id="op7" class="comppreco css-label" for="op7i">€2001 - €2500</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op8i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2501 AND 5000" data-compind1="8" data-compactiv1="no"/>
                <label id="op8" class="comppreco css-label" for="op8i">€2501 - €5000</label>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <div class="t">Velocidade</div><div id="compind2" class="incount t"></div>
            <input id="process" type="hidden" name="process" value='1 AND 4.2'>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op9i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1.50 AND 2.00" data-compind2="1" data-compactiv2="no"/>
                <label id="op9" class="compprocess css-label" for="op9i">1.5 GHz - 2 GHz</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">  
                <input id="op10i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2.50 AND 3.00" data-compind2="2" data-compactiv2="no"/>
                <label id="op10" class="compprocess css-label" for="op10i">2.5 GHz - 3 GHz</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op11i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3.10 AND 3.50" data-compind2="3" data-compactiv2="no"/>
                <label id="op11" class="compprocess css-label" for="op11i">3.1 GHz - 3.5 GHz</label>
            </li>   
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op12i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3.60 AND 3.90" data-compind2="4" data-compactiv2="no"/>
                <label id="op12" class="compprocess css-label" for="op12i">3.6 GHz - 3.9 GHz</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op13i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4.00 AND 4.20" data-compind2="5" data-compactiv2="no"/>
                <label id="op13" class="compprocess css-label" for="op13i">4 GHz - 4.2 GHz</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <div class="t">Ram</div><div id="compind3" class="incount t"></div>
            <input id="ram" type="hidden" name="ram" value='1 AND 2256'>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op20i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2 AND 2" data-compind3="1" data-compactiv3="no"/>
                <label id="op20" class="compram css-label" for="op20i">2 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op21i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4 AND 4" data-compind3="2" data-compactiv3="no"/>
                <label id="op21" class="compram css-label" for="op21i">4 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op22i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="8 AND 8" data-compind3="3" data-compactiv3="no"/>
                <label id="op22" class="compram css-label" for="op22i">8 GB</label>
            </li>   
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op23i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="12 AND 12" data-compind3="4" data-compactiv3="no"/>
                <label id="op23" class="compram css-label" for="op23i">12 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op24i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="16 AND 16" data-compind3="5" data-compactiv3="no"/>
                <label id="op24" class="compram css-label" for="op24i">16 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op25i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="32 AND 32" data-compind3="6" data-compactiv3="no"/>
                <label id="op25" class="compram css-label" for="op25i">32 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op26i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="64 AND 64" data-compind3="7" data-compactiv3="no"/>
                <label id="op26" class="compram css-label" for="op26i">64 GB</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <div class="t">Disco</div><div id="compind4" class="incount t"></div>
            <input id="disco" type="hidden" name="disco" value='1 AND 2512'>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op27i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="256 AND 256" data-compind4="1" data-compactiv4="no"/>
                <label id="op27" class="compdisco css-label" for="op27i">256 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">  
                <input id="op28i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="500 AND 500" data-compind4="2" data-compactiv4="no"/>
                <label id="op28" class="compdisco css-label" for="op28i">500 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op29i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1000 AND 1000" data-compind4="3" data-compactiv4="no"/>
                <label id="op29" class="compdisco css-label" for="op29i">1 TB</label>
            </li>   
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op30i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1120 AND 1120" data-compind4="4" data-compactiv4="no"/>
                <label id="op30" class="compdisco css-label" for="op30i">1 TB + 120 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op31i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1128 AND 1128" data-compind4="5" data-compactiv4="no"/>
                <label id="op31" class="compdisco css-label" for="op31i">1 TB + 128 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op32i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1256 AND 1256" data-compind4="6" data-compactiv4="no"/>
                <label id="op32" class="compdisco css-label" for="op32i">1 TB + 256 GB</label>
            </li>
            <li class="input">
                <input id="op33i" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2256 AND 2256" data-compind4="7" data-compactiv4="no"/>
                <label id="op33" class="compdisco css-label" for="op33i">2 TB + 256 GB</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the JS.js file

```
var inpreco=["","","","","","","","","","","",""];
var altpreco=["","","","","","","","","","","",""];
var inprocess=["","","","","","","","","","","",""];
var altprocess=["","","","","","","","","","","",""];
var inpram=["","","","","","","","","","","",""];
var altram=["","","","","","","","","","","",""];
var inpdisco=["","","","","","","","","","","",""];
var altdisco=["","","","","","","","","","","",""];
var compcount1=0;
var compcount2=0;
var compcount3=0;
var compcount4=0;

$(".comppreco").click(function(){compcount1=SuperFun(this,"#preco",inpreco,altpreco,"compind1","compactiv1",compcount1,"preco","1 AND 5000","listacomput.php",
"preco","process","ram","disco","preco","preco","preco");});

$(".compprocess").click(function(){compcount2=SuperFun(this, "#process",inprocess,altprocess,"compind2","compactiv2",compcount2,"processador_id","1 AND 16", 
"listacomput.php","preco","process","ram","disco","preco","preco","preco");});

$(".compram").click(function(){compcount3=SuperFun(this,"#ram",inpram,altram,"compind3","compactiv3",compcount3,"RAM","1 AND 64","listacomput.php", "preco",
"process","ram","disco","preco","preco","preco");});

$(".compdisco").click(function(){compcount4=SuperFun(this,"#disco",inpdisco,altdisco,"compind4","compactiv4",compcount4,"disco","1 AND 2256","listacomput.php","preco","process","ram","disco","preco","preco","preco");});

function SuperFun(element,input,inpArray,secArray,secIndex,inpActive,counter,msqlip,ending,ajax,input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7){
var inpValue=$("#"+element.id+"i").val();
var sIndex=$("#"+element.id+"i").data(secIndex);
var inpa=$("#"+element.id+"i").data(inpActive);
var secArray2=secArray.filter(Boolean);
if (counter==0){
  counter++;
  $("#"+element.id+"i").data(inpActive, "primary");
  inpArray[0]=(inpValue);  
}else
if (inpa=="no") {
  counter++;
  $("#"+element.id+"i").data(inpActive, "yes");
  inpArray[sIndex]=(" OR "+msqlip+" BETWEEN "+inpValue);
  secArray[sIndex]=(sIndex);
}else
if (inpa=="yes") {
  counter--;
  $("#"+element.id+"i").data(inpActive, "no");
  inpArray[sIndex]="";
  secArray[sIndex]="";
}else
if (inpa=="primary" && counter!==1) {
  counter--;
  $("#"+element.id+"i").data(inpActive, "no");
  inpArray[0]=$("input[data-"+secIndex+"*="+secArray2[0]+"]").val();
  inpArray[$("input[data-"+secIndex+"*="+secArray2[0]+"]").data(secIndex)]="";
  $("input[data-"+secIndex+"*="+secArray2[0]+"]").data(inpActive, "primary")
  secArray[$("input[data-"+secIndex+"*="+secArray2[0]+"]").data(secIndex)]="";    
} else
if (inpa=="primary" && counter==1) {
  counter--;
  $("#"+element.id+"i").data(inpActive, "no");
  inpArray[sIndex]="";
  inpArray[0]=ending;   
}
$(input).val(inpArray[0]+inpArray[1]+inpArray[2]+inpArray[3]+inpArray[4]+inpArray[5]+inpArray[6]+inpArray[7]+inpArray[8]+inpArray[9]+inpArray[10]+
  inpArray[11]);
$.post(ajax+"?"+input1+"="+$("#"+input1).val()+"&"+input2+"="+$("#"+input2).val()+"&"+input3+"="+$("#"+input3).val()+"&"+input4+"="+$("#"+input4).val()+
"&"+input5+"="+$("#"+input5).val()+"&"+input6+"="+$("#"+input6).val()+"&"+input7+"="+$("#"+input7).val(), function(data) {
  $("#paramount").html(data);
});
if (counter==0) {
  $("#"+secIndex).html("");  
}else {
  $("#"+secIndex).html(counter);
}
return counter;
};
```

The listacomp.php file (the AJAX file):

```
$pagina=1;
if (empty($_GET["pagina"]) || $_GET["pagina"] < 1) {$pagina = 1;}else 
{$pagina = intval($_GET["pagina"]);}
$quantidade = 3;
$offset = ($pagina - 1) * $quantidade;
$preco=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["preco"]);
$process=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["process"]);
$ram=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["ram"]);
$disco=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["disco"]);
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS computadores.id, computadores.nome, computadores.preco, processadores.velocidade AS velocidade, computadores.RAM, computadores.disco FROM computadores LEFT JOIN processadores ON computadores.processador_id=processadores.id WHERE (preco BETWEEN $preco) AND (processadores.velocidade BETWEEN $process) AND (RAM BETWEEN $ram) AND (disco BETWEEN $disco) LIMIT $offset,$quantidade";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo mysqli_error($conn);
$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
$contagem = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$total_resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($contagem);
$total_resultados = $total_resultados[0];
$ultima_pagina = ceil($total_resultados / $quantidade);
$link = "&quantidade=$quantidade";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {echo mysqli_num_rows($result) . " computadores<br>";}
    elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {echo mysqli_num_rows($result) . " computador<br>";}
    do {
        echo "
            <li class='entrada'>
                <img src='imagens/computadores/$row[id].JPG'>
                <div class='entradanome'>$row[nome]</div>
                <div class='entradacarac'>
                    Velocidade: $row[velocidade] GHz<br>
                    RAM: $row[RAM] GB<br>
                    Disco: $row[disco] GB
                </div>
                <div class='entradapreco'>$row[preco]€</div>
            </li>";
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
    echo "<div class='ajpaginacao'>";
    if ($pagina > 1) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($pagina - 1) . "$link'><span >&lt;</a>";
    }else {
        echo "<span>&lt;</span>";
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ultima_pagina; $i++){
        if ($i == $pagina) {
            echo "<span class=\"active\">$i</span>";
        }else {
            echo "<a href='?pagina=$i$link'>$i</a>";
        }
    }
    if ($pagina < $ultima_pagina) {echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($pagina + 1) . "$link'>&gt;</a>";}else {echo "<span>&gt;</span>";}
    echo "</div>";
}else {
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: there's quite a lot - and quite complicated - code for a rather simple task. You need to first reduce it into smaller chunks to verify which part does what you think it should and which doesn't.

Comment: Where do you send the `pagina` query parameter to the listacomp.php file?

Comment: @Sawny I dont send $pagina anywhere outside the listacomp.php file. it is created there ($pagina=1) and doesnt leave. The pagination code is in listacomp.php. Its all there.

Comment: @Adato From where in the javascript code do you send `pagina=*number*`. What is the value of `$_GET["pagina"]`?

Have you checked if the bug is in the PHP file or in the javascript code handling the AJAX? If you hardcode `$_GET["pagina"] = 2;`, do you see the second page or the first?

Comment: @Sawny the js.js file doesnt send $pagina anywhere. GET["pagina"] comes from the pagination code (the pagination DIV) which is in listacomp.php. GET["pagina"] is showing as "undefined". If i hardcode it, (to whatever number)  it only shows results and pagination when the number of pages reaches that number (after i click in enough labels). Before that its nothing. Im unable to check for bugs because it doesnt signal any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the pagination working. But i had to create another function inside the JS file just to change pages, using data-atribute in the ajax file which identifies each page.